# Yes, I would like (to)

Tags: modal-verbs

Are both answers to the question "Would you like...?" correct or there is must be "to" in the answer?

> **Yes, I would like.**
>
> **Yes, I would like to.**

Comment: "Would you like an apple?" "Yes, I would [like one]." "Would you like to come for a walk?" "Yes, I would [like to]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "like" is present, the "to" is essential (unless a noun or pronoun is added, e.g. "I would like that", which would also work).

Possible answers include:

- Yes, I would like to.
- Yes, I'd like to.
- I would like to.
- I'd like to.
- Yes, I would.
- I would.
- Yes.

But not:

- <strike>I would like.</strike>

Answer (score 1):

The "to" is obligatory.

In English, there are several words that can be stranded (left hanging at the end of a clause). Some of the words are prepositions: eg. "who are you talking **to**?", auxiliaries: eg. "Yes, I **can**", and the infinitive marker "to": eg. "Yes, I'd like **to**".

A lexical verb such as "like" in general cannot be left stranded. So it is not grammatically correct to say *"Yes, I'd like".